# Adding space between radio buttons in JSF 2.0 and IceFace

Tags: html, css, jsf-2

i have below code in JSF2.0, and i want output in proper alignment.

```
<ice:panelGrid columns="1">
    <ice:selectOneRadio styleClass="hpLabel planTdSecond" style="padding-left: 10px" value="#{dpsController.dpsVo.selectOne}" layout="pageDirection">       
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Employer" itemValue="emp" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Member" itemValue="member" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Broker/Sales Professional" itemValue="brkr" />
    </ice:selectOneRadio>
</ice:panelGrid>
```

I am getting output like below :

```
   0 Employer
       0 Member
0 Broker/SalesProfessional
```

I want output like :

```
0 Employer
0 Member
0 Broker/SalesProfessional
```

Comment: I think you can format your code better...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a simple aligment problem of your column, you could try something like this :

```
<style>
    .columnAlignLeft
    {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>

<ice:panelGrid columns="1" columnClasses="columnAlignLeft">
    <!-- Your current code -->
</ice:panelGrid>
```